# Cannot find module '_baseIsRegExp'

Tags: npm, gulp, babeljs

I am getting this error while running gulp, I already have `babel-register` installed.

```
[18:51:21] Requiring external module babel-register
    module.js:327
        throw err;
        ^

    Error: Cannot find module './_baseIsRegExp'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ndbsite\src\NdbSite.UI\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-class-properties\node_modules\babel-helper-function-name\node_modules\babel-types\node_modules\lodash\isRegExp.js:1:82)
        at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
        at Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
        at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (D:\ndbsite\src\NdbSite.UI\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:156:7)
        at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
```

seems I am missing some package. Not sure how to find it. Please Help.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried deleting and reinstalling `node_modules`? There's no reason that file would be missing unless an installation failed.

Comment: tried but still the same

Comment: Are you using `npm` v3? Given the long file path, it seems like you aren't. I'd try upgrading and reinstalling with that.

Comment: What's the stack trace you get now? It should be flatter.

Comment: @loganfsmyth somehow it was related to old packages that were not updated even when node & npm is updated. Resolution is to Delete old package & then `npm install` with new node & npm. Can you post new version comment as answer, I will accept it

Comment: If you figured it out, you can answer your own question, don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I was facing because of old packages referenced inside other Modules were not updated 
As suggested by @loganfsmyth in comment. I updated node & npm. Still issue exists since old packages were not updated inside the hierarchy.

Resolution is to delete old folders using rimraf and then npm install with new node & npm :

```
npm install rimraf -g

rimraf node_modules

npm install
```