# React app won't open in browser using yarn start or npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

React App won't open in browser using yarn start or npm start

node v 12.14.1
npm v 6.13.4

Steps:

1. npm install -g create-react-app
2. npx create-react-app hello-world
3. cd hello-world
4. yarn start

I get this message:

```
yarn run v1.17.3
$ react-scripts start
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:796
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './_baseGetTag'
Require stack:
- /Users/punchcode/Projects/hello-world/node_modules/lodash/isFunction.js
- /Users/punchcode/Projects/hello-world/node_modules/last-call-webpack-plugin/src/index.js
- /Users/punchcode/Projects/hello-world/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/src/index.js
- /Users/punchcode/Projects/hello-world/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
- /Users/punchcode/Projects/hello-world/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:793:17)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:686:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/punchcode/Projects/hello-world/node_modules/lodash/isFunction.js:1:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/punchcode/Projects/hello-world/node_modules/lodash/isFunction.js',
    '/Users/punchcode/Projects/hello-world/node_modules/last-call-webpack-plugin/src/index.js',
    '/Users/punchcode/Projects/hello-world/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/src/index.js',
    '/Users/punchcode/Projects/hello-world/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js',
    '/Users/punchcode/Projects/hello-world/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js'
  ]
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
➜  hello-world git:(master)
```

Comment: Try `npm install`. You might need to remove old packages https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39124836/cannot-find-module-baseisregexp

Comment: Since the OP is using yarn they would want to use `yarn install` instead of `npm install`. Using both npm and yarn can cause problems